# Restricting the "More Languages" button from showing for limited users in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, security

I tried to restrict the display of the 'More Languages' button for limited users in Sitecore by modifying the `read/write` language role in `/sitecore/system/Languages`, but it wasn't sufficient.

Is there a way I can manage permissions for this button?

[image: restrict More Languages in Sitecore]

Answer (score 2):

Go to `core` database.

Find `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Menues/Languages/More Languages` item in Content Editor

Set `deny` in access rights for `Everyone` like:

[image]

Administrators will still be able to see the item and the menu and no one else will be able to see the `More languages` option.